# Создание столбца по индексу

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

У меня есть DataFrame, в нем есть два столбца. Я хочу создать третий столбец, но чтобы он был на первом месте. 
На данный момент я делаю вот так:
Сначала создаю столбец

```
df1['Numbers' ] = getNum
```

Он создается последний, потом я его удаляю и вставляю на первое место

```
num = df1['Numbers']
df1.drop(labels=['Numbers'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df1.insert(0, "Numbers", num)
```

Можно как то сразу при создании поместить его по нужному индексу?
PS Только начал изучать pandas, много чего не знаю. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@Эникейщик показал наиболее идиоматичный и короткий способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882746/211923).

Иногда возникает необходимость отсортировать/упорядочить столбцы "на лету", чтобы использовать это дальше в "chained expressions". В этом случае можно воспользоваться методом [.reindex(..., axis='columns')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), т.к. метод [.insert()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable//generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) делает изменения "на месте" ("in place") и всегда возвращает `None`. Т.е. после него не получится вызвать следующий метод через точку.

Пример: дан след. DataFrame:

```
In [215]: df
Out[215]:
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
```

необходимо добавить новый столбец в качестве первого столбца и посчитать сумму всех столбцов.

```
In [216]: df.assign(x=[10,11]).reindex(['x'] + df.columns.tolist(), axis='columns').sum()
Out[216]:
x    21
a     5
b     7
c     9
dtype: int64
```

пошагово:

```
In [217]: df.assign(x=[10,11])
Out[217]:
   a  b  c   x
0  1  2  3  10
1  4  5  6  11

In [218]: df.assign(x=[10,11]).reindex(['x'] + df.columns.tolist(), axis='columns')
Out[218]:
    x  a  b  c
0  10  1  2  3
1  11  4  5  6

In [219]: df.assign(x=[10,11]).reindex(['x'] + df.columns.tolist(), axis='columns').sum()
Out[219]:
x    21
a     5
b     7
c     9
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Если getNum это значения столбца, то просто

```
df1.insert(0, "Numbers", getNum)
```